# Is defining an exception as a variable (except Exception as e) best practice even if you're not accessing e at any point?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, error-handling

Which if the better practice, if we're not going to do anything with the exception `e`:

```
except Exception:
    pass
```

OR

```
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

I'm just curious as to whether it's best practice to write `except Exception as e:` even if we're not accessing the `e` object afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't name the exception if you're not going to use it.

You can actually see from the disassembly that the `except Error:` way is more efficient, because it doesn't have to create the `e` variable:

```
>>> def foo1():
...     try:
...         1 / 0
...     except ZeroDivisionError:
...         pass
...
>>> def foo2():
...     try:
...         1 / 0
...     except ZeroDivisionError as e:
...         pass
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo1)
  2           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            12 (to 14)

  3           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              6 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
              8 POP_TOP
             10 POP_BLOCK
             12 JUMP_FORWARD            20 (to 34)

  4     >>   14 DUP_TOP
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ZeroDivisionError)
             18 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32
             22 POP_TOP
             24 POP_TOP
             26 POP_TOP

  5          28 POP_EXCEPT
             30 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 34)
        >>   32 END_FINALLY
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(foo2)
  2           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            12 (to 14)

  3           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              6 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
              8 POP_TOP
             10 POP_BLOCK
             12 JUMP_FORWARD            34 (to 48)

  4     >>   14 DUP_TOP
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ZeroDivisionError)
             18 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       46
             22 POP_TOP
             24 STORE_FAST               0 (e)
             26 POP_TOP
             28 SETUP_FINALLY            4 (to 34)

  5          30 POP_BLOCK
             32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 STORE_FAST               0 (e)
             38 DELETE_FAST              0 (e)
             40 END_FINALLY
             42 POP_EXCEPT
             44 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 48)
        >>   46 END_FINALLY
        >>   48 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             50 RETURN_VALUE
```

It's also immediately clear to anyone reading your code that if you don't name the exception you are not doing anything with it (logging it, altering it, etc).